# Liferay 6.2 GA6 - LDAP "userPassword" attribute can't be reached

Tags: active-directory, ldap, liferay, liferay-6

I've desperately been trying to connect my liferay installation with our MS AD to import the users into the MySQL DB so that all the existing users from the AD are able to log in to the liferay instance.

I configured everything as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueGWq.jpg

When I "test the users", I get everything I want except for the "password" which should be displayed encrypted or in asterisk symbols. No matter what I do, the attribute does not show up.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OsXe.jpg

Any tips?

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: password is not retrieved from ldap because it is chiphered. Remember that liferay has to be configured to have same chiper algorithm of ldap server, this is necessary to authenticate the user

Comment: This is rather a system administration than a programming question. You typically don't want to import hashed passwords, but you want to evaluate them through other means on LDAP servers - e.g. on log in through the "bind" method. While in the end you'll import the user, the password won't come from LDAP - at max, as it is known at log in time, it can be saved and hashed by Liferay then and there. But don't count on duplicating AD's password hashing.